# Bootstrap notification panel like facebook messages dropdown

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I want to show a message dropdown using bootstrap.  This is very similar to the messages dropdown that comes in facebook (not the full page view, but just the dropdown only).  Can someone please share the sample markup to get this done.

Comment: I think you must elaborate a little bit more, like a code example demonstrating what you are trying to do. There is tons of examples for bootstrap navbar out there.

Comment: Can you mark my answer as correct?

Answer (score 18):

If you are using bootstrap 3 you can see and working example here:
http://infinite-woodland-5276.herokuapp.com/index.html

Working example: http://codepen.io/igcorreia/pen/htdxl

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">

        <p class="lead">Roll over the button on the left to see a dropdown</p>
        Rollover dropdown:
        <!-- Our Special dropdown has class show-on-hover -->
        <div class="btn-group show-on-hover">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
            Action <span class="caret"></span>
          </button>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>

        Regular dropdown:
        <!-- Single button -->
        <div class="btn-group">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
            Action <span class="caret"></span>
          </button>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
body{
    padding:10px;
}

.show-on-hover:hover > ul.dropdown-menu {
    display: block;    
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the pointers.  What I am looking for is something like the messages dropdown in http://codepen.io/igcorreia/pen/htdxl.  Can you please provide the markup for that.